# codeigniter : form validation jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have a form name `nama kategori` and then when someone input the `nama kategori`that already exist, i want the button become unclickable like when the button being clicked it's not gonna do anything, the problem is i manage to get the `error message` when input the existing `nama kategori`, but when i click the button it's still send the data and inputting the data, for more info look the images below

> Success Display Error Message
>   [image]

Then i clicked button **"Tambah"**[image]

it's still adding the data into the tables, i want to prevent that, i want when the button clicked it's not gonna do anything below are my code

> **JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check1=0;
    $("#kategori").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var nama = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'cekData/kategori/nama_kategori/'+nama,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#report1").text("");
                check1=1;
            }else{
                $("#report1").text("*choose another kategori");
                check1=0;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> **VIEW**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m8 l6 offset-m2 offset-l3" align="center">
       <form action="<?php echo site_url('kategori/insertKategori') ?>" method="post">
       <div class="input-field">
           <input id="kategori" name="kategori" type="text" maxlength="40" class="validate" required>
           <label for="kategori">nama kategori</label>&nbsp;<span class="error" id="report1"></span>
       </div>   
       <br/>
           <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-1">Tambah</button>
       </form>
       <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **CONTROLLER**

```
public function cekData($table, $field, $data){
    $match = $this->MKategori->read($table, array($field=>$data), null, null);
    if($match->num_rows() > 0){
        $report = 2;
    }else{
        $report = 1;
    }
    echo $report;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make following changes to your jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check1=0;
    $("#kategori").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var nama = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'cekData/kategori/nama_kategori/'+nama,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#report1").text("");
                check1=1;
                $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled','');
            }else{
                $("#report1").text("*choose another kategori");
                check1=0;
                $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```